# Show mid-roll ads in video player using plugin

Tags: javascript, html, video, vast

Trying to develop custom video player using Vast 2.0 and video.js. I got success in showing pre-roll ad with the skip button functionality.

I am showing my custom videos as ad.

Can someone help me in how could I show multiple mid-roll like after some span of minutes?

Updating XML file for reference:

```
<VAST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vast.xsd">

    <Ad id="176" >

        <InLine>
            <AdSystem version="2.0">ONION</AdSystem>
            <AdTitle>In-Stream Video</AdTitle>
            <Description>Grand Budapest Hotel_Fridays</Description>

            <Impression><![CDATA[http://reporting.theonion.com/videoadtracker/track.gif?videoAd=176&event=impression]]></Impression>
            <Creatives>
                <Creative sequence="1" AdID="">
                    <Linear>
                        <Duration>00:00:10</Duration>
                        <TrackingEvents>
                            <Tracking event="start"><![CDATA[http://reporting.theonion.com/videoadtracker/track.gif?videoAd=176&event=start]]></Tracking>

                            <Tracking event="start"><![CDATA[http://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/trackimp/N2998.Onion/B7912634.16;dc_trk_aid=279982600;dc_trk_cid=57339121;ord=[timestamp]]]></Tracking>





                        </TrackingEvents>

                        <VideoClicks>
                            <ClickThrough><![CDATA[http://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/trackclk/N2998.Onion/B7912634.16;dc_trk_aid=279982600;dc_trk_cid=57339121;ord=[timestamp]?http://www.foxsearchlight.com/thegrandbudapesthotel]]></ClickThrough>
                        </VideoClicks>

                        <MediaFiles>

                            <MediaFile id="1" delivery="progressive" type="video/mp4"><![CDATA[media/test.mp4]]></MediaFile>

                            <MediaFile id="1" delivery="progressive" type="video/webm"><![CDATA[http://v.theonion.com/onionmedia/videos/videometa/1521/test.webm]]></MediaFile>

                        </MediaFiles>
                    </Linear>
                </Creative>
            </Creatives>
      </InLine>

    </Ad>

</VAST>
```

Answer (score 0):

The information, when a VAST ad should be played is not part of the VAST-XML but part of the player implementation and configuration. The client should be able to decide whenever he wants to play an ad.

Just find the mid of your video or define a fixed amount of time for streams and start playing the Ad. As you have the player already, this should be an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

With video.js, you can use timeupdate event to trigger whatever you want at a certain time by checking currentTime value.

Try the following snippet and look at its console, at sec 5 you can trigger your ads showing action etc..

```js
var player = videojs('my-video');
player.on('timeupdate', function(){
  var currentTime = this.currentTime();
  console.log(currentTime)
  if(Math.round(currentTime)===5){
    console.info('Trigger your code here');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video.js"></script>


<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>
```